# Displaying date on correct format when joining it with text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date on cell R10 which is 26/03/2021

But then in another cell I added the following

```
="Date correct as end of business " &R10
```

Which displays "Data correct as end of business 44281"

How can I change it so that it displays the date rather than the number?

Comment: **Sidenote;** you got so many open questions and it would be polite to revisit those and see where you can accept/upvote answers that have answered your questions. **On-topic:** Use `TEXT()` to reformat your data correctly and append it to your custom text use `&` operator.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that now I have selected answers for my questions and they are closed.

Comment: @Sam You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JvdV suggested use `TEXT()` function like below.'

```
="Date correct as end of business " & TEXT(R10,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```